# Every intersection and union of initial segments of $E$ is an initial segment of $E$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The definition of initial segment is in [the link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InitialSegment.html).

*Proposition.* Every intersection and union of initial segments of $E$ is an inital segment of $E$.

Let $E$ be well-ordered. Let $U$ and $V$ be initial segment of $E$, i.e., for all $x,y$ in $E$, if $\left\{ y\in U:x < y\right\}$ and $\left\{ y\in V:x < y\right\}$ then we have $x\in U$ , $x\in V$. We need to show that $U\cup V$ is an initail segment of $E$.

**Can you check my introduction of the proof and can you help for proof?**

Comment: What is a segment? Do you mean union and intersection of *initial* segments?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг edited

Comment: If $U$ is an initial segment, then there exists a $k \in E$ such that $U = \{ a \in E : a < k\}$. Similarly for $V$, there exists $l \in E$ such that $U = \{ b \in E : b < l\}$. Now, can you proceed?